# Is there a package for approximating a function using Chebychev Polynomials?

Tags: julia

Is there a package for approximating a function using Chebychev Polynomials? 
I was formerly using Matlab and there was a package called Compecon that can approximate a function using Chebychev Polynomials.
I am wondering if there is any packages similar for Julia.
Or is there any packages in C or fortran or Python that can do this?

Thanka a lot!

Comment: Was ApproxFun useful?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out [ApproxFun.jl](https://github.com/dlfivefifty/ApproxFun.jl), it may be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/QuantEcon/CompEcon.jl and related https://github.com/QuantEcon/BasisMatrices.jl have the capacity I believe.